# How do I get a project and call its "compile" method from inside a method?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have a method that has some logic to know whether to include a dependency via `compile` or via `compile project`. But when i do the second one, it says:

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':my-lib'] on project ':parent-lib' of type org.gradle.api.Project

How do I do a compile on the project inside a method?

```
ext.includeSpecial = {moduleName ->

    //...elided...

    compile project( ":${moduleName}" )
}

dependencies {

    //This works
    //compile project(':my-lib')

    //But this does not
    includeSpecial( "my-lib" )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to invoke the `compile` method, it is defined only for some hidden Dependency Handler class, rather define a method that returns the argument to compile/
Inside the `dependencies` closure, you can write groovy code and call methods such as:

```
def specialDependency() {
   // if / else
}


dependencies {
    compile specialDependency()
}
```

You can get more results such as this https://discuss.gradle.org/t/programmatically-adding-dependencies/7575/12
by searching for  "programmatically add dependencies in gradle".

Some more explanation, gradle is not actually declarative, so the dependencies block

```
dependencies {
    compile "foo"
}
```

is actually a closure, same as this:

```
project.dependencies({DependencyHandler handler ->
    handler.compile("foo");
})
```